# How many ways can Nicole form a committee?

Tags: combinations

> Nicole needs to form a committee of 3 from a group of 8 research
>   attorneys to study possible changes to the Superior Court. If two of
>   the attorneys are too inexperienced to serve together on the
>   committee, how many arrangements of committees can Nicole form?

My teacher tells me to express this in terms of combinations. The question says that I need to find the total of both the number of combinations for 3 experienced attorneys and 2 experienced attorneys / 1 inexperienced attorney.

Because they asked for "how many arrangements", order does not matter, so I should use combinations. I have

3 experienced attorneys:

$\frac{6!}{3!(6-3)!}$=20 (please verify)

2 experienced / 1 inexperienced attorney:

(Please help me with the 2 experienced / 1 inexperienced attorney one. I'm so confused.)

Comment: You calculated the number of ways of selecting three experienced attorneys correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

For the two experienced, one inexperienced case: You need to choose two out of six experienced attorneys (how many ways?); and one out of two inexperienced attorneys (how many ways?)

Comment: 6!/[2!(6-2)!] + 2!/[1!(2-1)!] ways?

Comment: Multiply the results, don't add them.  For each way to do the first step, there are so many ways to do the second step.

Comment: 6!/[2!(6-2)!] * 2!/[1!(2-1)!] = 30 is this correct?

Comment: Are we multiplying, not adding, because of the word "and" in selecting 2 experienced committees "and" 1 inexperienced committee?

Comment: @comb  The word "and" is an indication that you need to multiply.